# Linking a twitter search to a custom tableview cell

Tags: twitter, uitableview, xcode4.2

okay, here's what I've been scratching my head over for the last few days. I have created a custom cell for my table view. I have created a separate class (customCell.h) for this cell and linked them together in Xcode. 
The custom cell has four UIlabels which I have declared in the .h file of the custom cell and linked to the custom cell via storyboard.

I have imported the customCell.h header file into the .h file of my table view controller

I am trying to do a search on twitter, and then populate the table view and custom cell with the details of the various tweets. The issue is I don't know how to link the results of the tweet to the 4 UIlabel outlets in my custom cell.

When I am declaring some of the outlets of the custom cell in my table view implementation file (even though I've imported the .h file of the custom cell) xcode is saying that it does not recognise the name

I've copied the coding below detailing as far as I can get. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"THIS IS WHERE MY TWITTER SEARCH STRING WILL GO.json"]];

        NSError* error;

        tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSArray *arrayForCustomcell = [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of the UITableViewCell, which is the default class for tableview cells. In your case, you have to create an instance of your customCell class (which extends the UITableViewCell class). You have to do this in you cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if ( cell == nil )
{
    cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Get the tweet
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I hope this helped you out!

Steffen.